# Understanding a proof from algebraic k-theory

Tags: projective-module, algebraic-k-theory

I've been reading Milnor's notes on algebraic K-theory, and have trouble understanding the last step of the proof of Lemma 3.2. Here is the set up.

Let $A$ be a ring, and $P$ a finitely generated protective $A$-module. Define a map
$$\operatorname{Aut}(P) \to K_1 A$$
as follows. Choose $Q$ so that $P\oplus Q$ is free and send $\phi$ to $\phi\oplus 1_Q$, which lives in $GL(A^n)$ for some $n$.

The lemma is just to show this is well defined, so showing that a different choice of basis for $P\oplus Q$ or a different choice if $Q$ just conjugates in $GL(A^n)$.

He writes that if we choose $Q'$ instead, with $P\oplus Q' \cong A^t$, then $Q \oplus A^t \cong Q' \oplus A^n$, which I understand. But then he just says that it follows that changing $Q$ only alters the embedding by an inner automorphism. How does this follow?

Comment: You used the wrong slash.

Comment: You haven't done the colimit yet. So you might see $Q'=Q \bigoplus A$ and get things in $GL(A^n)$ and $GL(A^{n+1})$. You haven't done the upper left embeddings to make them in the same space. Then you can conjugate.

Comment: @AHusain I understand the upper left embedding into $GL(A)$, but I still don't see how $\phi \oplus 1_Q$ and $\phi \oplus 1_{Q'}$ are conjugate.

Comment: Just mean you should say $i_{n} (\phi \bigoplus 1_Q)$ and $i_{n+1} (\phi \bigoplus 1_{Q'})$ are conjugate. Otherwise they are not even in the same group so meaningless question to ask without the embedding.